# what is the exact meaning of master table,staging table,configuration table,transaction table,temp table ?

Tags: plsql

Can any one please let me know what is the exact meaning of master table,staging table,configuration table,transaction table,temp table ? 
previously am in Java .now i am new to the Pl/sql and peoplesoft application.
sp please elaborate if  you know the perfect answer?

Comment: if you don't know the answer don't give negative comments.

Comment: If you don't know how the site works, please don't tell others how to use it.

Comment: To get a "perfect answer", you need to ask a "perfect question" :)

Answer (score 2):

I used google for 5 minutes and I've found:

> In Simple way
>   Master Table means your basic data which you want to
>   use another place like Address Book , Employee List , Product List.
>
> What is a Staging table ?
>
> A staging table is just a regular SQL server table. For example, if
>   you have a process that imports some data from say .CSV files then you
>   put this data in a staging table. You may then decide to apply some
>   data cleaning or business rules to the data and move it to a different
>   staging tables etc...
>
> Transaction table means if doing any transaction like payment gateway
>   , Account credit , Debit like this. Which each transaction needed
>   different different master table.

You should read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, you'll understand why the negative votes. And I can guarantee you, it's not because they don't know the answer.